Design and performance of Bi-Planar Rotors or Propellers
I have been doing a bit of a deep dive on coaxial rotors and propellers recently and ended up reading into the NASA Puffin vtol concept. I found out that it was supposed to have a "bi-planar" rotor, that is to say two sets of blades rotating in two planes, and rotating in the same direction. (IE: not opposite like a coaxial). They claimed it was more efficient than a coaxial rotor and less noisy.
Is that true? Is there any literature on how this bi-planar rotor (or propellers) works?

Photos suggest the Puffin had what looks like just two coaxial rotors.  Where does NASA say otherwise?  Was each rotor actually four-blade instead?  Or, within each coaxial rotor, did one blade-pair really go in the same direction as the other blade-pair?

coaxial   just means "on the same axis" - it does NOT mean contra-rotating...

BLUF: a stacked (i.e., coaxial rotors that are co-rotational) rotor system is generally more efficient (consensus seems to sit on the order of 5-10% in general cases) and quieter than an isolated rotor of the same size and solidity that are trying to produce the same amount of thrust. Two isolated rotors will always be more efficient in producing the same thrust as two coaxial/stacked/tandem rotors since they will not have to face performance degradation due to rotor-rotor interactions.
Most stacked rotor references in the below are drawn from a 2019 NASA study entitled An Exploration of the Performance and Acoustic Characteristics of UAV-Scale Stacked Rotor Configurations, a (paywall) 2023 study entitled Exploration of stacked rotor designs for aerodynamics in hover, and Investigation of the Flow Fields of Coaxial Stacked and Counter-Rotating Rotors Using PIV Measurements and URANS Simulations from 2021. This is by no means a comprehensive summary of stacked rotor research, but the citations in those should help.
Note on terminology: in the below, coaxial will always refer to coaxial rotors spinning in opposite directions, and stacked will always refer to coaxial rotors that are co-rotational.
Complete answer:
The driving factor for coaxial rotors is, usually, a way to resolve a competition between footprint and performance. Thinking of the Kamov Ka-50, its coaxial rotor enables higher maneuverability through a reduction in moment of inertia (think of the transmission and rotor weight that would otherwise hang out on the tail and tail boom). This also means that it has a smaller footprint, making a derivative of it, the Ka-52, of interest for naval applications. For military applications, performance is, generally, the driver. This is, coincidentially, why you don't see a bunch of civilian coaxial helicopters...they require more fuel to operate, and cost is the primary driver for that market. Drones break the curve with that a little, because electrical power is a little cheaper than traditional fuels on a joule for joule basis, and volume (and weight) are commodities when it comes to operating them, hence why it makes sense that interest in coaxial or stacked systems is a hot topic for them.
That said, stacked designs are not new. The AH-64 Apache (first flight Sept 30, 1975) actually has a stacked tail rotor (see below) with a small azimuthal offset. From what you can see of the individual blades, you can verify that this is not a coaxial rotor system, but a stacked one.

While this was initially done to improve mechanical access, it was found to reduce the 4/rev vibrations of the rotor (i.e., impulsive forcing from each blade passing over the tail boom, which would normally occur with 90 degrees of separation for a 4-bladed rotor) and, ultimately, noise. In the 2023 study mentioned earlier, it was found that, for the model rotor tested, depending on the aziumuth offset between rotors, the peak-to-peak thrust variations of the stacked rotor system could be smoothed out significantly, decreasing changes in thrust over a rotation by up to 60%. This indicates a dramatic decrease in vibration and noise.
This was confirmed by the 2019 NASA study cited earlier. The study went on to measure the power required and noised produced by a model rotor as it produced a certain amount of thrust, both in stacked and side-by-side configurations. This, as shown below, indicated a small (4-5%) increase in efficiency (as measured by power loading) as opposed to a pair of co-planar rotors (dZ/R = 0 refers to the co-planar case).

It is interesting to note that coaxial rotors have been tested with a similar idea. In a 2013 study, it was found that a model coaxial rotor, when producing the same thrust as a single, isolated rotor, have a greater efficiency (almost 10% greater). This is to be expected, given swirl recovery at the least. However, when compared to a pair of side-by-side rotors, the coaxial configuration generated almost 20% more induced drag, requiring almost 20% greater power for a given operating point. This is suspected to be principally due to strong blade/blade interactions when they pass each other, generating a strong drop in pressure between the blades when they pass and decreasing the amount of lift produced by the lower rotor (and increasing vibrations/etc.). See below for an illustration.

All that said, the 2019 study was primarily experimental, and the authors note several issues with a companion numerical analysis they were doing. The primary issue is that it required a proscribed inflow and a proscribed wake geometry, and the simulation results did not match experimental data. Other authors (see 2023 study) postulate, through, that there is a beneficial blade-vortex interaction, generating upwash on the lower blades. Their study as well as this one from the 2021 Vertical Flight Society forum indicates a strong relationship between thrust production/power requirements in a stacked rotor system and the placement of the lower rotor with respect to the tip vortex of the upper blade. This vortex can increase the inflow (and thus the power loading) around the tip of the lower blade, generally increasing aerodynamic efficiency of the lower rotor. This can be seen in the below comparison of thrust production with and without strong blade vortex interaction in a stacked rotor system as compared to isolated and coaxial rotors from the 2023 study that I cited earlier. Aerodynamic efficiency appeared to maximize in their study at azimuth offsets of  5-10 degrees when the axial separation between rotors was 0.2 diameters, 20-30 degrees at 0.3 diameters, and between 30-90 degrees at 0.4-0.5 diameters of separation.

However, there is no free lunch. By co-axially positioning two rotors, and in close proximity, you get two simultaneous effects. There is some effect of the lower rotor on the upper, although the upper rotor generally tracks with the inflow velocity of an isolated two-bladed rotor (i.e., the same rotor that is being stacked), as shown below (from 2023 study). The lower rotor does pull additional inflow through the upper rotor, which is especially noticeable near the blade tips. By contrast, however, the lower rotor is forced to ingest the upper rotor's wake, resulting in a dramatically increased inflow velocity as compared to the isolated case. Whereas inflow velocity varies inversely with power loading, this decreases the efficiency of the lower rotor substantially.


The pair of side-by-side rotors (think Focke-Achgelis 61 or 223, or Mil-12) will involve a larger volume of air into the production of lift, accelerating it by less. Like with a wing of higher span, this will be more efficient than stacking the rotors, regardless of their direction of rotation. Of course, losses from interaction will come on top. –

That's a great way to explain it. I will add!

This technology has been called numerous things over the years.
Hamilton Standard investigated 'Variable Camber Propellers'.
There was some old research done by Sikorski that called it 'Variable Geometry Rotors'.
Most current literature in this area calls it 'Stacked co-rotating rotors'.
Search for those key words and you will find many papers investigating the idea in different ways.
Like many technologies, it can be applied in different ways to different effects.
For example, if it is applied in a way that maximizes the noise reduction, it might result in an efficiency loss or a reduction in maximum thrust available.  Conversely, if it is applied in a way that maximizes the thrust attainable, it may result in a noisy design.
Note, the two blade pairs are not always kept at 90 deg separation.
